# Magento 2 form field toggled type

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, forms, fieldsets, magento2.2

I want to create a toggle input option in magento  2 like this:

[image]

but i don't know what type of field is that, right now i'm using select dropdown like this:

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'featured',
            'select',
            [
                'label' => __('Featured'),
                'title' => __('Featured'),
                'required' => true,
                'options' => ['1' => __('Yes'), '0' => __('No')],
                'value' => $partner['featured']
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: did yoy found the solution

Comment: I need same toggle button in my new payment method can you guys please guide how can I achieve it.  please follow link .https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296371/magento2-how-to-create-toggle-button-yes-no-in-admin-side?noredirect=1#comment426710_296371

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is **checkbox** form field. Which is included in UI Component library. You cannot use this toggle in `$fieldset->addField()`. You need to **create a form with UI component** to create this type of toggle.

```
<field name="status">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
            <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
            <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
            </item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Comment: Hi, Can you show or share link for Js component for this toggle checkbox that hides fields on on/off

Comment: @AjwadTaqvi Check this components `Magento_Catalog/js/components/visible-on-option/yesno`

Comment: Hi Prince. Your answer is pretty good. I am using it to add a new field in the custom option value section. I can create the toggle switch with the help of your code and save the value in the database. But the problem is that the toggle not selected by default according to a database value. Is there anything I need to do for that? Like, add a script code etc?

Answer (score 3):

Below solution is working for me. Hope it will help someone.

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'my_field',
    'checkbox',
    [
        'name' => 'my_field',
        'class' => 'admin__actions-switch-checkbox',
        'label' => __('My field label'),
        'value' => $model->getData('my_field'),
        'checked' => $model->getData('my_field'),
        'after_element_js' => '
            <label class="admin__actions-switch-label" for="my_field">
                <span class="admin__actions-switch-text" data-text-on="'.__('Yes').'" data-text-off="'.__('No').'"></span>
            </label>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                require(["jquery"], function($){
                    $("#my_field").change(function() {
                        if($("#my_field").is(":checked")) {
                            $("#my_field").val("1");
                        } else {
                            $("#my_field").val("0");
                        }
                    });

                    $("#edit_form").submit(function() {
                        $("#my_field").prop("checked", true);
                    });
                });
            </script>
        '
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Nalin Savaliya it is working for me. thanks a lot

Comment: this solution works fully, including showing the correct value and sending the correct value to the Save action. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While I recommend using the Ui component method. You can use the following (slightly roundabout) way to add a toggle checkbox if you only have **addField** at your disposal.

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'my_field',
    'checkbox',
    [
        'label' => __('My field label'), 
        'required' => false, 
        'value' => '1', 
        'name' => 'my_field', 
        'class' => 'admin__actions-switch-checkbox', 
        'after_element_js' => '
            <label class="admin__actions-switch-label" for="my_field">
                <span class="admin__actions-switch-text" data-text-on="'.__('Yes').'" data-text-off="'.__('No').'"></span>
            </label>
        '
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just came across the same situation. We can use the **onchange** handler for toggle instead of writing custom Jquery script.

```php
$fieldset->addField(
            'featured',
            'checkbox',
            [
                'label' => __('Featured'),
                'title' => __('Featured'),
                'name' => 'featured',
                'data-form-part' => $this->getData('target_form'),
                'onchange' => 'this.value = this.checked;',
                'checked' => $partner['featured'],
                'class' => 'admin__actions-switch-checkbox',
                'after_element_js' => '
                    <label class="admin__actions-switch-label" for="customer_form_featured">
                        <span class="admin__actions-switch-text" data-text-on="'.__('Yes').'" data-text-off="'.__('No').'">
                        </span>
                    </label>
                '
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below Checkbox component code for Magento 2.2.0 and later version, because old structure will be deprecated at some point.

```
   <field name="status" sortOrder="10" formElement="checkbox">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">yoursourcegoes here</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <dataType>boolean</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Status</label>
            <dataScope>status</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <checkbox>
                <settings>
                    <valueMap>
                        <map name="false" xsi:type="number">0</map>
                        <map name="true" xsi:type="number">1</map>
                    </valueMap>
                    <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                </settings>
            </checkbox>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```